# How to create extjs view for json file

Tags: php, json, extjs, yii

I am working in extjs + Yii framework. my server side is in Yii and client side is in extjs. I am giving yii framework output to extjs as input. Now from Yii i am sending json:

```
CJSON::encode(array("questionId"=>$questionid,"question"=>Question,"Options"=>$optionList,"CorrectOptionId"=>$CorrectId,"UserSelectedOption"=>$Usersoption));
```

So i am getting json output:

```
{"Questions":[
{
            "questionId": 1,
            "question": 'Who will win the series1212?',
            "options": [
                {

                    "optionId":1,
                    "option":'Aus',
                    "questionId":1
                },
                {

                    "optionId": 1,
                    "option": 'india',
                    "questionId":1
                },
                {

                    "optionId": 1,
                    "option": 'England',
                    "questionId":1
                },

            ]
            "CorrectOptionId":1,
            "UserSelectedOption":2,

        } ,{-------}
    ]

}
```

I have MVC formatted code:

`QbqnsModel.js`

```
Ext.define('Balaee.model.qb.QbqnsModel',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    idproperty:'questionId',//fields property first position pk.
    fields: ['questionId','question','languageId','userId','creationTime','questionStatusId','keyword'],
    hasMany:{
            model:'Balaee.model.qb.QbqnsoptionModel',
            foreignKey:'questionId',
            name:'options',
        },
        proxy:
        {
            type:'ajax',
            api:
            {
            },//end of api
            reader:
            {
                    type:'json',
            },//end of reader
            writer:
            {
                    type:'json',

            },//End of writer
        }
```

`QbQnsStore.js`

```
Ext.define('Balaee.store.qb.QbqnsStore',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'Balaee.model.qb.QbqnsModel',
    autoLoad: true,
    proxy:
    {
        type:'ajax',
        api:
        {

            read:'data/question.json',

        },
        reader:
        {
            type:'json',
            root:'questions',

        }
    }
});
```

And Qbqnsview.js as-

```
 Ext.define('Balaee.view.qb.qbqns.QbqnsView',
    {
            extend:'Ext.view.View',
            id:'qbqnsViewId',
            alias:'widget.QbqnsView',
            //store:'kp.PollStore',
            store:'qb.QbqnsStore',
            config:
            {
                tpl:'<tpl for=".">'+
                    '<div id="main">'+
                    '</br>'+
                //  '<b>Question :-</b> {pollQuestion}</br>'+
                    '<h1 id="q">Question :-</h1> {question}</br>'+



        '<tpl for="options">'+     // interrogate the kids property within the data '<tpl if="optionId == parent.UserSelectedOption && optionId != parent.CorrectOptionId">'+
'<p>&nbsp&nbsp<input type="radio" name="{parent.questionId}" value="{option}" class="red">&nbsp{option}</p>'+
'</tpl>'+
'<tpl if="optionId == parent.CorrectOptionId">'+
    '<p>&nbsp&nbsp<input type="radio" name="{parent.questionId}" value="{option}" class="green">&nbsp{option}</p>'+
'</tpl>'+
'<tpl if="optionId != parent.CorrectOptionId && optionId != parent.UserSelectedOption">'+
    '<p>&nbsp&nbsp<input type="radio" name="{parent.questionId}" value="{option}">&nbsp{option}</p>'+
'</tpl>'+
                '</tpl></p>'+
                '<p>---------------------------------------------------------</p>'+
                '</div>'+
                '</tpl>',
            itemSelector:'div.main',    
        }
});// End of login class
```

It is displaying questions and its options correctly. Now on click of button i want to show once again all questions,options,its actual correct option and user selected option.
So i want to bind this above json output to extjs store and want to create view to display question,its options via radio buttons,correct option in green color. So how to design extjs part to display such view . i am very new to extjs...So can you please guide me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your specific question-
 use below code with in for loop -

```
    '<tpl if="optionId == parent.UserSelectedOption && optionId != parent.CorrectOptionId">'+
    '<p>&nbsp&nbsp<input type="radio" name="{parent.questionId}" value="{option}" class="red">&nbsp{option}</p>'+
    '</tpl>'+
    '<tpl if="optionId == parent.CorrectOptionId">'+
        '<p>&nbsp&nbsp<input type="radio" name="{parent.questionId}" value="{option}" class="green">&nbsp{option}</p>'+
    '</tpl>'+
    '<tpl if="optionId != parent.CorrectOptionId && optionId != parent.UserSelectedOption">'+
        '<p>&nbsp&nbsp<input type="radio" name="{parent.questionId}" value="{option}">&nbsp{option}</p>'+
    '</tpl>'+
```

Comment: sir....i made changes as above.Bt correctoptionId and Userselectedoption fields are not in table. So it is not accessing these fields. So what i need to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use sample code below -

```
        var store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
            url: 'get-images.php',
            root: 'images',
            fields: [
                'name', 'url',
                {name:'size', type: 'float'},
                {name:'lastmod', type:'date', dateFormat:'timestamp'}
            ]
        });
        store.load();

        var tpl = new Ext.XTemplate(
            '<tpl for=".">',
                '<div class="thumb-wrap" id="{name}">',
                '<div class="thumb"><img src="{url}" title="{name}"></div>',
                '<span class="x-editable">{shortName}</span></div>',
            '</tpl>',
            '<div class="x-clear"></div>'
        );

        var panel = new Ext.Panel({
            id:'images-view',
            frame:true,
            width:535,
            autoHeight:true,
            collapsible:true,
            layout:'fit',
            title:'Simple DataView',

            items: new Ext.DataView({
                store: store,
                tpl: tpl,
                autoHeight:true,
                multiSelect: true,
                overClass:'x-view-over',
                itemSelector:'div.thumb-wrap',
                emptyText: 'No images to display'
            })
        });
        panel.render(document.body);
```

Comment: Thanx sir for reply...i have edited my code. So can you please tell me what changes i need to do for displaying correct optionid in green and user's selected option in red if its wrong. All this required data i am getting from json from yii action. Please help me sir...

Comment: Please edit your answer if you like to add more information but do not post a new except there is any really good reason.